# Is there a way to do a ' ls -R | grep "aname"* | rm; to remove multiple files in multiple directory

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, ls, rm

I have installed (compiled) emerald. The command `make uninstall` didn't work (there is no makefile as it is just a script). So I decided to remove the file manually. But there were a lot of files.

I've tried some things but it didn't work. So I came here to ask for some advice.

- Is there a command with `ls -R | grep blabla*` that I can add to display file directory (it only displays filename)
- Is there a true `ls -R | grep bla* | rm` ?

Answer (score 6):

If 'aname' shall be the starting part of the filename, it would be, from the current directory:

```
find -name "aname" -delete
```

Btw.:

```
grep "bla"* somewhere
```

is almost always false, since grep already makes partial matches, which means, it finds bla, blafasel and xybla with simply

```
grep bla somewhere
```

Deleted older part of answer, because of misunderstanding:

<strike>From the current directory, if you look for the word 'aname' in all files, you can just use:</strike>

```
find -exec grep "aname" {} ";" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i didn't help me. I'm looking for a command that recursively find "myfilename*" into child folders. Just like 'ls -R | grep name*'... and delete them.

Comment: Ok it's good, i didn't notice that find recursively look into directory... Case resolved ;) thanks. I was just looking for : sudo find -name bla* -delete; :D so simple

Comment: @Cyclic: Don't forget to mask `"bla*"` with quotes; else it won't work. May I ask you to upvote helpful posts and to accept one of the helpful answers? (clicking the ^ signs before the answers and the symbol, similar to &radic; )

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is a combination of `xargs`, `find`, and `rm`.

`find` will make a list of all the files matching your conditions, and then write them (null terminated) to `stdout`, which will be piped to `xargs`. `xargs` will take the null terminated strings and use them as arguments to `rm`.

```
find -L /path/to/dir -name "*name*" -print0 |xargs -0 -r  rm
```

source: http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2007/10/find-xargs-pipe.html

Comment: The `-delete` find action could be of help.

Comment: I can, but if the OP is looking for a general solution that can be used with more than just rm then he should look into this form.

Answer (score 0):

In-between the other answers: you can invoke `rm` without without needing the `xargs` program.  In fact you can usually use the `exec` option to `find` instead of `xargs`.

To invoke `rm` as few times as possible, on big batches of files:

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*name*" -exec rm {} +
```

To invoke `rm` once for each file:

```
find /path/to/dir -name "*name*" -exec rm {} ";"
```

There are also more-elaborate options to `find` that will change to the directory before executing the command.